# Spring Data Rest Neo4j creating relationships

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How do you create Neo4j relationships in Java while using @RepositoryRestResource to export domain objects to Rest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this or not.   I had asked a similar question, didn't receive any answers but found my own workaround for the little app I'm building to learn more in Spring/Angular2.  Check out the answer I posted to my question here: [Spring Data REST Neo4j create a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571396/spring-data-rest-neo4j-create-a-relationship/38637752#38637752)